# $.get response not having responseJSON method, but when I bind it in Chrome dev tools, it does?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making this AJAX call:

`let g = $.get("http://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=seinfeld", {dataType: 'json'});`

If I try to call `g.responseJSON`, expecting an array of objects, I get `undefined`.

But if I log `g` to the console, I can clearly see it's an object with a responseJSON property (an array of objects). And if I rightclick that object and bind it to a temporary variable in Chrome's devtools, calling `.responseJSON` on *that* works.

I'm totally baffled by this and I just can't think of any reason this would be happening. I clearly see that the property exists, it exists on copies, why would it not be working here?

Answer (score 1):

[`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) returns the jqxhr object, so if you want to access the response from the server you could subscribe to the `.done` event and inside this event you will get the actual server response:

```
g.done(function(response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

The event will be invoked at a later stage, when the actual response from the server is received.